# How to change the MIDI tempo with scheme?

Tags: lilypond, midi, tempo, lily-scheme

I would like to create a function which would automate some tempo changes in my score (it would be hidden on the score with something like `\override Score.MetronomeMark #'transparent = ##t`, indeed the goal is to add a bit of expressiveness into the MIDI output).

I manage to add a tempo change on the score (with `#(make-music 'TempoChangeEvent ...)`), but it doesn't affect the MIDI output, like `\tempo` would do. But it is exactly what I would need though.

I tried to change the context property `tempoWholesPerMinute`, but it does nothing at all.

```
\version "2.18.2"
\language "english"

mytempo = #(define-music-function (music) (ly:music?)
  #{
    #(make-music 'TempoChangeEvent
      'metronome-count 180
      'tempo-unit (ly:make-duration 2))

    \applyContext #(lambda (context)
      (ly:context-set-property! context
        'tempoWholesPerMinute
        (ly:make-moment 180 3)))

    #music
  #})

\score {
  \new Staff \relative c' {
    \mytempo c
    d e f g
  }
  \layout {}
  \midi {}
}
```

How can I change the MIDI tempo by using a custom function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tempoWholesPerMinute` property is interpreted by the `Tempo_performer` which lives in `Score` context, so changes in your current context are not visible to the performer.  So you need

```
(ly:context-set-property (ly:context-find context 'Score) ...
```

or alternatively

```
\context Score \applyContext ...
```

In general, if you know what kind of LilyPond construct produces something you desire and you want to express it in Scheme without conveniently just writing `#{ ... #}`, it is easiest to just put `\displayMusic` before it in its LilyPond form and then read what appears in the console output.

Here `\tempo 4 = 60` will produce

```
(make-music
  'SequentialMusic
  'elements
  (list (make-music
          'TempoChangeEvent
          'metronome-count
          60
          'tempo-unit
          (ly:make-duration 2)
          'text
          '())
        (make-music
          'ContextSpeccedMusic
          'context-type
          'Score
          'element
          (make-music
            'PropertySet
            'value
            (ly:make-moment 15)
            'symbol
            'tempoWholesPerMinute))))
```

which basically (in the second half) corresponds to

```
\set Score.tempoWholesPerMinute = 15
```

that is implemented by LilyPond as a case of

```
\context Score ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't think about calling `\displayMusic` with `\tempo`:) It's working now, by adding `(make-music 'ContextSpeccedMusic ...)`